# Howto create sql files without database connection using hibernate 5

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

In hibernate 4 I used `config.generateSchemaCreationScript(dialect);` to generate sql creation script files from our classes. After update to hibernate 5 (5.6.5.Final to be precise) I'm trying to create the same behavior.

Tried the following:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
for (Class<?> type : types) {
  config.addAnnotatedClass(type);
}
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = config.getStandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySetting(Environment.DIALECT, MariaDBDialect.class).build();
Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();

SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport();
schemaExport.setHaltOnError(true);
schemaExport.setFormat(true);
schemaExport.setDelimiter(";");
schemaExport.setOutputFile(new File("create.sql"));
schemaExport.createOnly(EnumSet.of(TargetType.SCRIPT), metadata);
```

This code gives me lots of warnings "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver" and "java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!". It seems that creation of the metadata object already tries to create a database connection. But I don't have/want a database connection, I only want to create sql files from the database objects.

I've also tried to do `schemaExport.execute(EnumSet.of(TargetType.SCRIPT), Action.CREATE, null, serviceRegistry);`. This will still try to setup a database connection and fails on a nullpointer exception for metadata.

How can I create sql files from my Configuration in hibernate 5 without a database connection?

Answer (score 3):

Same issue here and could not find a way to prevent it from doing so, and as a workaround I have used hsqldb: read hibernate.properties + only modified driver/url/user/password to those of hsqldb, and only then handed the properties to hibernate to process them: this way hibernate gets a database to connect to (even though it does not need one for this task), while dialect remains intact, which is important for DDL/sql-scripts generation; tested and proved to work.